# How to convert video to gif and mp3 that sync using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert video to gif with audio. The two should match when played at the same time.

The command I use somehow generates results that's a bit off.

To create gif:

```sh
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i input.mp4 -t 4 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -filter:v "scale=-1:300" out.gif
```

To create mp3:

```sh
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i input.mp4 -t 4 out.mp3
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the slicing.

Answer (score 0):

Untested: You could try one of these two options below. If still not working then please provide a short clip (MP4 link) that can be tested to give you required solution...

**Option 1)** Try using `-itsoffset` instead of `-t`...

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -itsoffset 4 -i input.mp4 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -filter:v "scale=-1:300" out.gif

ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -itsoffset 4 -i input.mp4 out.mp3
```

**Option 2)** Avoid issue of non-matching times for keyframes (of video track vs audio track)...

First trim the video (get's whatever audio is available at nearest video keyframe to your time):

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i input.mp4 -t 4 trimmed.mp4
```

Then use trimmed MP4 (will have synced audio) as source for your output GIF and MP3.

```
ffmpeg -i trimmed.mp4 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -filter:v "scale=-1:300" out.mp4

ffmpeg -i trimmed.mp4 out.mp3
```